TypeError: some keyword arguments unexpected
I'm trying to write a parser for page. I'm using LxmlSoup library.
so the deal is:
html = requests.get('https://www.mcdonalds.com/ua/uk-ua/eat/fullmenu.html').text
soup = LxmlSoup(html)
urls = soup.find_all('a', class_='cmp-category__item-link')
items = []

for url in urls:
    link = "https://www.mcdonalds.com" + url.get("href")

    item_html = requests.get(link).text
    item_soup = LxmlSoup(item_html)

    item_name = item_soup.find('span', class_='cmp-product-details-main__heading-title').text()

And the error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\111\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    item_name = item_soup.find('span', class_='cmp-product-details-main__heading-title')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\111\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\LxmlSoup\LxmlSoup.py", line 25, in find
    elements = self.findel(tag, **attrs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: some keyword arguments unexpected

I just don't know what i should pass in this function exactl

Why is this tagged beautifulsoup if you're using LxmlSoup instead?

Looks like a bug in LxmlSoup. Commenting out the @njit(parallel=True) decorator on the LxmlSoup.findel method fixes it.

@Barmar faster , newer

@Barmar i should edit my py file right? not the library's

The bug is in the lilbrary.

I wasn't asking why you're using LxmlSoup, I asked why you tagged the question with something not related to the library.

And lxml != LxmlSoup.

If the bug is in the library, then you need to edit the library's file.  Don't be afraid of that.

okay i switched to the BeautifulSoup and have this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
@Barmar

That means that BeautifulSoup(item_html) is returning None. You need to check for that before trying to search it.

But I'm not sure why it would return None. Check the documentation for the reason.

I actually have strong complexity of the task. Look, i have such structure unique div, then non-unique UL contains 4 LI items and these LI items have span which i need to pull out.item_nutritions = item_soup.find("div", class_= "cmp-nutrition-summary cmp-nutrition-summary--primary").find_all("li", class_= "cmp-nutrition-summary__heading-primary-item")

so i skipped the UL because i found that DIV. BUT, How to pull out the span tag and it's value? find_next method? @Barmar

Sounds like you need to post a new question, this is totally unrelated to your original question.

In general, after you call find() you need to check that it found something before you try to use the result in other calls.

@Barmar okay but what to do if too much tags and classes are nested?

I doin't really understand the problem you're having. Please post a new question so you can explain it clearly. Include sample HTML that demonstrates the problem.
